# Facebook toolkit session issue

Tags: app

I have created a Facebook app using the toolkit and have seem to run into what seems like a session caching issue. I'll use Pat (@metadaddy)'s test page to illustrate

- Login to facebook
- Go to https://testfbtk3-developer-edition.na14.force.com/
- The page displays your photo and if you have not approved the app then Facebook OAuth dialog appears.
- Logout of facebook and login as a different user in facebook
- Relaunch the above URL and you will notice that the page still displays the information of the first user.

Even if you clear the cache, the page still displays the information about the first user which has manifested into a serious problem for my app.

Has anyone found how to fix this problem?

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, but I tested using chrome incognito tab: logout and login as different user - shows the correct data. e.g. the logged in user. Maybe check what cache/history you have to clear in order to get correct value displayed.

Comment: @Saariko - the incognito tab doesn't work quite the same as a regular browser window. I see the issue in a quick test.

Comment: @DCBoy - I'll look into fixing this. It may be possible to have some JavaScript that detects a mismatch between the logged in FB user id and the session in the site. Failing that, what would be useful? Logout link in the site? Configurable session lifetime? Both of the above?

Comment: @metadaddy I think logging out makes sense.

Comment: @DCBoy Try https://testfbtk3-developer-edition.na14.force.com/ now - I've turned off the automatic login, using 'Login' and 'Logout' links instead (autologin doesn't work well with a Logout button, since, if you logout and return to the same page, you just get logged in again). Let me know if this looks good and I'll push the code to GitHub and create a new unmanaged package.

Comment: @metadaddy After I logout from Facebook, the [page](https://testfbtk3-developer-edition.na14.force.com/) still shows details using my facebook account. The desired effect should be to prompt the facebook login page if am not logged in.

Comment: The page doesn't know that you logged out from Facebook, but, if you refresh it after you logged out, it will log you out of the site (unfortunately, this is after the page starts to render, due to when the JavaScript executes). I'll try building something with a timeout to periodically check if the FB session is still there.

Comment: @DCBoy Try it now - there is a timer set so that it checks the user's status every 5 seconds. Open https://testfbtk3-developer-edition.na14.force.com/ in one window, and log in. Log out from FB in another window, and watch the toolkit sample page...

Comment: @metadaddy Looks good, great work! Cant wait to implement it my app.

Comment: OK - will do my best to get it checked in over the next day or so. Will post an answer here with how to enable the auto-logout when I do.

Comment: Took me somewhat more than 'a day or so', but the `FacebookCheckUser` component is new in Version 3.3 of the toolkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 3.3 of the [Force.com Toolkit for Facebook](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-Facebook) fixes this issue by providing a `FacebookCheckUser` Visualforce component that periodically checks that the current user has a valid Facebook session, and logs them out of the Force.com app if the Facebook session is no longer valid. Usage:

```
<!-- appId - Facebook Application ID -->
<!-- userId - ID of currently logged in Facebook User -->
<!-- timeout - Timeout, in seconds -->
<c:FacebookCheckUser appId="{!appId}" userId="{!me.id}" timeout="60" />
```

The new component is in use on the toolkit sample page - try logging in to https://testfbtk3-developer-edition.na14.force.com/ in one browser window, then logging out of Facebook from another window of the same browser. The toolkit sample should log you out within about 5 seconds or so.